# Table with large math column?

Tags: tables

I want do something like:

```
\begin{tabular}{ll}
  Text explanation in the left column. Math on the right. & $\int_0^1 \sum\limits_z$ \\
\end{tabular}
```

However, in the above, the math renders in small math mode. I want the larger math mode that comes with the `{align}` environment, however, I can't embed `{align}` blocks in the tabular expression. I can use something other than tabular, but I do want a text column to the left and an `align` like environment on the right. How can I do this?

Comment: In the math expression you want the larger math mode, just type in `\displaystyle`.

Answer (score 3):

`\displaystyle` solves the problem:

```
\begin{tabular}{ll}
  Text explanation in the left column. Math on the right. & $\displaystyle\int_0^1 \sum\limits_z$ \\
\end{tabular}
```